# Request failed: unexpected response data from server null

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I have to develop a page for SharePoint 2013 where I am retreving data from a list and showing it.

I have a list called `Test` , below is my code to retreive data from list.

```
function getDataValue(Oname) {
    
    set_value();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('test');
    var CamlQuery ="<query><where><eq><fieldref name="Opportunity_x002d_Name"><value type="Text">"+Oname+"</value></fieldref></eq></where></query>";
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<view>"+CamlQuery+"</view>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
   
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    
  
        
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        
        
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    
    var value = '';
    var sum=0;

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

          value=   oListItem.get_item("Opportunity_x002d_Name"); 
         // alert(value);
         
         ID=oListItem.get_item("ID");
         
        // alert(ID);
         
          getBALData(oListItem);
        
          getPMData(oListItem);
          
          total();
            //Totalsum=Totalsum+parseInt(value);
    }

   
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The error I am getting is

> Request failed unexpected response data from server.
>
> null

What might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your CAML Query, **fieldref name** and **value type** are written in double quotes and your whole query is already placed in double quote.
Please try following query and let me know if its working:

```
   var CamlQuery = "<query><where><eq><fieldref name='Opportunity_x002d_Name'><value type='Text'>"+Oname+"</value></fieldref></eq></where></query>";
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake here in the main code its already in single codes